# Analog voltage level shifter

Tags: voltage, analog, level-shifting

I am looking for a way to shift a low analog voltage level to a higher analog voltage level. For example, input 0.53 V and output 1.53 V (increase by 1 V) or input 1.38 V and output 3.38 V (increase by 2 V). Is there a way to do that?

What I found online are digital level shifters that shift 3.3 V to 5 V or 5 V to 3.3 V. That is not what I need. I need a way to increase analog voltage level.

Comment: Try looking for op-amp applications. Try this one from Analog devices (I've never heard of A. instruments btw): https://www.analog.com/en/design-notes/singlesupply-op-amp-forms-noninverting-level-shifter.html#:~:text=The%20single%20op%2Damp%20circuit,voltage%20with%20the%20input%20signal.

Comment: Since you don't need much (any?) gain for the signal, a single opamp circuit can add a DC level shift to an analog signal. For more detail, please provide more details. Signal frequency range? Signal amplitude range? Input impedance (loading on the signal source)? Accuracy and stability of the offset voltage? Adjustable offset value? [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: To confirm, a digital level shifter is not suitable for analogue applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common task, with at least a dozen solutions!

I'll outline some here, in the hope that they make sense to you. Let's start with the summing amplifier, which employs an op-amp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYehtk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When all of the resistors have the same value (here I used 10kΩ) the relationship between the many inputs and single output is:

$$ V_{OUT} = -(V_{IN1} + V_{IN2} + V_{IN3}) $$

Note the minus sign, indicating that the result is actual the sum, negated. I use voltage sources to provide inputs of +2V, +1.5V and −1V, so the output (as you can see displayed on voltmeter VM1) is:

$$ -(+2V + 1.5V - 1V) = -2.5V $$

You can have as many (or as few, including only 1!) inputs as you like, each requiring only one extra resistor. So, you could dispense with IN3 altogether, apply +2V at IN2, and your signal goes to IN1. That would give you the relationship:

$$ V_{OUT} = -(V_{IN1} + 2V) $$

Now you're asking, but what if I don't want it negated? Well, how about adding another stage, another summing amplifier with only 1 input? That would technically be called an "inverting amplifier, since it's not summing anything, but it is still inverting:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDaP8z.png)</sup>

The second stage "re-flips" the signal the right way up again, by once more multiplying by −1. \$V_{IN1}\$ above is a sinusoidal signal, shown here in blue, with the resulting \$V_{OUT}\$ in orange:

[image]

As you can see, the output is exactly the same as the input, just shifted upwards by 2V.

Another way to shift the signal up or down in potential, by some fixed amount \$V_{OFS}\$, is to literally just add or subtract using something that has exactly that voltage across it. I'm thinking of a cell or battery:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL6tsy.png)</sup>

This is obscenely simple. You know that the right end of BAT1 is exactly 2V higher in potential than its left end, so naturally, the relationship between the potentials at IN and OUT1 is:

$$ V_{OUT1} = V_{IN} + 2V $$

Similarly, the right end of BAT2 is 3V *lower* in potential than the left, so:

$$ V_{OUT2} = V_{IN} - 3V $$

Look at the simulation results, where \$V_{IN}\$ is blue, \$V_{OUT1}\$ is orange, and \$V_{OUT2}\$ is tan:

[image]

That last solution may be simple but the problem is that batteries run out, or get accidentally charged, depending on the direction of current through them. Instead of using batteries and cells which have to be replaced or maintained, we tend to use zener diodes. These have the property of maintaining a (roughly) constant voltage across them, when current is forced through them the wrong way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fChaGH.png)</sup>

In these designs we have to provide a potential significantly higher or lower (depending on the direction of current we want through the diode) than the maximum/minimum we expect the output to ever be, so that current is *always* flowing through the diode. The arrows show current direction, which will of course be from higher potential to lower. Notice how the diodes are facing in the opposite direction, being "reverse biased". This is how it performs:

[image]

The last technique I will share uses constant current sources, to push a known, fixed amount of current through a resistance. By Ohm's law we know that if the current through the resistor is fixed, and the resistance itself doesn't change, then the voltage \$V=I \times R\$ across the resistor must also be constant.

So, by forcing a known and fixed current through a resistance, we have essentially created something with a known potential difference across it, just like the batteries from before, and just like the zener diodes above, and we can adapt those designs to incorporate this idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgbfQI.png)</sup>

It's necessary to create a suitable current source or sink, but here's an example of the above circuits using bipolar transistors to perform that role:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDSqzy.png)</sup>

You're probably fed up with this by now, last demo:

[image]

Each of these designs has certain benefits, and certain caveats, too numerous to cover here, but at least you have a few options to try.

All of the above designs can be simulated, so I encourage you to click "simulate this circuit" for any that interest you, and mess around with them in CircuitLab.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

In analog world usually voltage level can be shifted by **scaling** (multiply the input by a constant) or by **offsetting** (adding a constant value to the input).

Usually scaling voltage is done by using an amplifier such as op-amp/transistor or a transformer and the most common is the positive feedback op-amp like the one shown here:
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/

As for offset circuits there are many different variations and solutions, most of them also involves op-amp - for example the summing amplifier can be used here as shown here:
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html

Hope this answer will help you.